# Accidentally deleted xorg.conf files, need to restore X11

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, desktop-environment

Was trying to get nvidia stuff to work properly on my Arch hybrid GPU laptop, edited `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and ran `nvidia-xconfig`, ended up totally breaking my Desktop Environment to where trying to startx would just freeze at the terminal. Deleted my `xorg.conf` and `xorg.conf.d` hoping X would just restore the files to fix whatever I broke.

This fixed the freeze problem, I can now `startx` into my Qtile DE, but my `xorg.conf` & `xorg.conf.d` files are still gone and now my touchpad scrolling is not inverted like I had it set before.

I've tried doing `X -configure` to restore the files, but that creates the config file in the wrong location and with `.new` in the name: `Your xorg.conf file is /root/xorg.conf.new`. It also doesn't recreate a `xorg.conf.d` folder.

I copy the `xorg.conf.new` file into `/etc/X11/` as `xorg.conf` and reboot, but when I `startx` it immediately crashes, with the only error I can see being something about losing connection to the server.

How can I totally restore my `/etc/X11/` contents so I can have functioning `xorg.conf` files again to set options like natural scrolling?

Comment: See the minimal configuration, then try it https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA#Minimal_configuration

Comment: FYI [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) is available on Arch https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Etckeeper, you should install it. It automatically commits everything in /etc to the version control system of your choice (default: git). *"A pacman hook auto-commits changes before a system-upgrade and file permissions are tracked, which version control does not normally support, but is important for files like /etc/shadow"*. It's too late for etckeeper to help you right now, but will allow you to revert from similar disasters in future.  Also, get into the habit of making regular backups

Comment: And for the next time: **rename** `xorg.conf.d` and `xorg.conf` instead of removing them. Even better, keep the originals of configuration files for some time before you edit them.